# "In" versus "at"

Tags: prepositions, definite-article

I'm confused about when to use *in* and when to use *at*.

Here's an example of a phrase I use in email communication:

> Please find the daily report at attachment.

Is "at attachment" correct, or should I say "in attachment"? (Also, should I add "the" in front of "daily report"?)

Comment: Welcome to ELL, but you have made the same mistake as when you posted previously at EL&U: there are too many questions here. The Stack Exchange model works best when there is one answerable question per post. I strongly recommend you visit the [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site, which is a question-and-answer site rather than a traditional discussion forum.

Comment: I regard them all as usage of preposition. And thats why i quote them all in one question. :'(

Comment: Ray, welcome to ELL! As [RegDwight told you when you posted this question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132986/questions-about-prepositions#comment274970_132986), this is many questions in one. You should only post one question in each post (though you are more than welcome to post multiple questions!). I am going to edit this question so that it only asks 1 question. You may re-ask the others if you like. Questions 1 and 2 were similar, so I've kept them as one question here. If I have misstated your questions in my edit, please let me know.

Comment: @Ray-Von-Mice That makes them *related* questions, but it doesn't make them the *same* question.

Comment: Some definitions list more than a dozen defintions for _at_, and more than 20 definitions for _in_. We are not going to deliniate between all of those (sometimes overlapping) usages and definitions in a single Stack Exchange question. A question like "When do I use _in_, and when do I use _at_?" will be closed as being too broad. That's what dictionaries are for. However, if you have a question about a particular usage, you may inquire about that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the article, I would include it. In fact, I would write:

> Please find the daily report **in the attachment**.

or:

> You can find the daily report **in the attached file**.

When I think of the word *in* used without an article, I think of phrases such as *in love, in jest, in concert*. In such cases, the word *in* essentially means "in a state of."

However, when using the word *in* to mean "inside of something," I would normally expect to see an article: *in the house, in a box, in the file*, and *in the attachment.*

Concerning which article to use, I would favor *in* over *at*. However, we are dealing with bits stored in cyberspace, where locations are a bit muddled, so my ears aren't all that much bothered by using *at*, either.

> Where can I find the daily report? I can find it at the attachment.

As I said, I much prefer *in*, but I don't find *at* to be utterly unacceptable.

Comment: As a computer programmer I would recommend using "in the attachment" cause attachment here is a box of data. The usage of attachment is only a box of extra things that you want your recipient to take with the message. Which also requires an extraction from mail when recipient wants to see what's in it.

Comment: Cheers guys, your answers really help.